# How to disable Xcode's '"ProjectName" is a project downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?' dialog?

Tags: xcode

This is not a question on how to disable the warning when opening files or apps downloaded from the internet but instead it is about Xcode Projects.

New with Xcode 7.3 released yesterday whenever a project is opened for the first time that was downloaded from the internet a warning pops up asking

> “ProjectName” is a project downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure
>   you want to open it?

How do I disable this warning from popping up?

Comment: Have you looked through the Xcode Preferences for any new settings?

Answer (score -1):

```
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Path/ProjectName
```